# GET and POST on the same route

Tags: node.js, post, get, request, restify

I'm building rest end point server (nodejs and restify).

I need to support the same route for two type of client's requests , one for GET and the other for POST.

Currently I solved it by this way :

```
server.get('/foo' , _ProcessRequest);
server.post('/foo' , _ProcessRequest);

function _ProcessRequest(req, res , next){...}
```

But I was wondering if there another way to support this type of request

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Personally the way you have your route structured I find to be the cleanest without use Router Middleware to abstract away the `.get()` and `.post()` calls. Since your question asks for other ways to do this here are others ways that you could structure your Route handlers to achieve the same funcitonality.

One way is to structure your routes would be to use `router.route()` and then specify a handler for each HTTP Method.

```
server.route('/foo')
  .get(_ProcessRequest)
  .post(_ProcessRequest)
```

Alternatively you could modify `_ProcessRequest` to have a condition that checks `req.method` with a more middleware style handler using `next()` to short circuit requests to `/foo` that aren't a GET or POST.

```
server.use('/foo', _ProcessRequest)

function _ProcessRequest(req, res, next) {
  // If not either a GET or a POST then continue to next handler
  if (req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'POST') {
    return next() 
  }

  // Request is a HTTP GET or POST so perform logic
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , could you explain why do you think it's not worth to use Router middleware  in my case ? I was thinking it'll give me a better flexibility , am I wrong ?

Comment: second solution didn't work for me , getting ---- >AssertionError: handler (function) is required